# Segment Fault (Core Dumped) C

Tags: c

I am writing a simple program that reads a file, however I'm having a problem using `fscanf` for reading the file. I've assured that the variable char has enough space for each line in the file but I don't know why I keep having this error.

Each lines contains info for a node in a graph, the first number is the id of the node, the next one is how mane nodes are connected with it, a maximum of 16.

This is the code I've written:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXPROC 16

struct task{
 int valid;
 int next[MAXPROC];
 int id;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 struct task tasks[MAXPROC];

 FILE *grafo;
 if(argc < 1)
 {
     fprintf(stderr, "Need file name to start \n");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 if((grafo = fopen(argv[1], "r"))!= NULL)
 {
     fprintf (stderr, "Could not open file \n");
     exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 char line [MAXPROC+19]; 
  
 while((fscanf(grafo,"%s",line))!= EOF )
 {
     printf("%s", line);
 }

 fclose(grafo);
 return 0;
}
```

I add 19 to `MAXPROC` because I need space for the id, the comas and number of nodes connected.

I know I can assign memory to char using `malloc` and reading the line char by char with `getc`, but I want to keep it simple.

This is the info contained in the file I am reading:

```
0,0
1,1,0
2,1,0
3,1,0
4,2,1,5
5,2,2,3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use fgets() instead of fscanf(), this will protect your program against buffer overflow. Your problem is not having sufficient space or not, this is to avoid buffer overflow, since segmentation fault means that a buffer overflow occured.

Comment: I suspect `argv[1]` is NULL. You should test for `argc < 2`.

Comment: What's the command you are using for running the command. Do you pass a file name, if so, argvc will be atleast 2.

Comment: I type .\read_graph filename.txt

Comment: I didn't write them on the question

Comment: What is `#define MAXPROC = 16` supposed to mean really? Doesn't your compiler complain about that?

Comment: Sorry I misstyped on the question, I'll edit it

Comment: ... and `(fscanf(grafo,"%s",line))!= EOF`  is wrong. `fscanf(grafo,"%34s",line) == 1` would be right, though `line` implies that you think you'll be reading a line, but you'll only read a word.

Comment: It doesn't change anything, I keep having the same error

Comment: `if (argc < 1)` should be `if (argc < 2)` and `if ((grafo = fopen(argv[1], "r")) != NULL)` only exits the program if the file was actually opened correctly. You need to reverse the condition: `if ((grafo = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)`

Comment: Try [this](https://godbolt.org/z/jT3zv6WKP)

Comment: @Jarler – 
How do you know that you're _having a problem using `fscanf`_?

Comment: "Sorry I misstyped on the question, I'll edit it " might mean that you need to be more thorough with providing a [mre] that really represents your problem. Best practice is to work with the code you provide here as MRE, i.e. copy it back home, build it, run it, observe it. Do not copy code from home and then try to edit it into a MRE.

Comment: evil typo: `if((grafo = fopen(argv[1], "r"))!= NULL)` Here you exit with an error message if `fopen()` **succeeded**. And if `frafp == NULL` you continue ...

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Yes, that's exactly the message I tried with an hour ago. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo ah xorry, I've overread that part of your comment

Comment: OT: `while(fscanf(grafo, "%s", line) != EOF )` should be `while(fscanf(grafo, "%34s", line) == 1)`. Also don't be so tight with the buffer size: trying to use a buffer that you think is *exactly* the right size will often bite you: be generous.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree, but as I pointed out before, `line` is misleading since it'll only read a word.

Comment: @TedLyngmo somehow I overlooked your earlier comment, although if there is no whitespace in the line, the whole line will be read.

Answer (score -2):

The Core file it gave you (Core dumped) contains information about when and why your program crashed. Low Level Learning has a great video about it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3T3ZDquDDVg